# url redirection with masking in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect from one url to another like this. I am using cpanel htaccess

When user goes to `www.domain1.com/sdomain`, it should redirect to `www.mydomain.com/sdomain` but in address bar it should display as `www.domain1.com/sdomain`.

I am not getting how to do this masking and redirection using .htaccess.

Somebody please help me in doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22514296/2817442 you or me will have to check it.