# URL Mask/Cloak with redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-masking

Am trying to do the following. My website is hosted on

www.sitehost.com/uk

But I own this domain.

www.mainsite.co.uk

Is it possible to redirect the user hitting www.mainsite.co.uk to www.sitehost.com/uk but retain the www.mainsite.co.uk?

I tried doing .htaccess redirect and it worked but it changed the URLs from www.mainsite.co.uk to www.sitehost.com/uk

Ideally it would work like so...

www.sitehost.com/uk/post/20

can be accessed via

www.mainsite.co.uk/post/20

I tried mod_proxy but it didn't seem to work all the way. Anyone know how to do this? Is this even possible with Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if `mod_proxy` is enabled in your Apache config.

Once `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` are enabled place this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` file of `sitehost` host:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sitehost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mainsite.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

`P` flag is used for proxying the request to external URL.

Comment: This works! Thanks so much.

Am guessing the {REQUEST_URI} handles any subfolders navigated on www.sitehost.com?

Comment: Yes `%{REQUEST_URI}` represents request UURI part with query string.